# Understanding Spring JPA native query under the hood

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to learn more about Spring JPA and what happens under the hood when a native JPA query (using PostgreSQL) is defined and called in a Repository class. I have tried searching online but all posts are related to defining and using native queries.

I am more interested to learn about what happens when my SpringBoot application calls a method that is annotated with @Query. I am mainly looking into this to try and understand the performance of executing such a query within Java.

Can anyone point me to a resource which goes in depth on what exactly happens under the hood when using Spring JPA?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone point me to a resource which goes in depth on what exactly happens under the hood when using Spring [DATA] JPA?

The authoritative source for this kind of information is the [source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa).
Let me point you to some places of interest.

Basically the following happens:

1. [find and extract the query from the annotation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryMethod.java#L257).
2. [possibly create a count query from that](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java#L67).
3. [replace spell expression with parameters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/QueryParameterSetterFactory.java#L127).
4. [add ordering if applicable](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java#L83).
5. [prepare the query with the `EntityManager`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/AbstractJpaQuery.java#L225).
6. [register parameters](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java#L92).
7. [add pagination limits](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java#L632).
8. [execute the query](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L88).
9. [transform result](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java#L104).

Answer (score 0):

1. Output log to view what SQL query really generated and executed

For example, in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.jpa=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate=debug
```

[SpringBoot log reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels)

2. Check the source code of spring-data-jpa here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/query/JpaQueryExecution.java